# custom x axis label and tooltip in dojo chart

Tags: charts, dojo, label

My json looks like this

```
var jStore = {
    "   identifier": "cpu",
    "items": [
        {
            "Time": "02:52",
            "Used": 100,
            "Idle": 0
        },
        {
            "Time": "02:57",
            "Used": 100,
            "Idle": 0
        }....
 ]
};
```

I create a datastore and adding to the chart,

```
var realStore =  new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({data: jStore});
var Ser = new dojox.charting.DataSeries(realStore, {query: {Idle: "*"}     }, "Idle");
var Ser1 = new dojox.charting.DataSeries(realStore, {query: {Used: "*"}     }, "Used");

chart.addAxis("x");
chart.addAxis("y", {  vertical: true, fixLower: "major", fixUpper: "major" });

            chart.addSeries("Used ",Ser);
                chart.addSeries("Idle",Ser1);
```

the chart is rendering properly but the xaxis values are taken default (1,2,3..).
But i need to give the axis value as the Time in my json.
Xaxis should be like 02:52,02:54,02:56

Also in the tool tip it showing only the value i have given the series. But i would like to add the value+ xaxis value. Say for example 100 at 02:54.
Could someone help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify custom labels for each value as follows:

```
mychart.addAxis("x", {fixLower: "minor", fixUpper: "minor", natural: false,
                                font: "normal normal 10pt Arial",
                                 labels: [{value: 1, text: "Q2 FY11"},
                                          {value: 2, text: "Q3 FY11"},
                                        {value: 3, text: "Q4 FY11"},
                                        {value: 4, text: "Q1 FY12"}]
                                });
```

You can also specify custom tooltip text as follows:

```
mychart.addSeries("Series A", [{ y: 2.3, tooltip: "FFFF"}, { y: 3.5, tooltip: "GGGG"}]);
```

In your case since you are using a store, the JSON that feeds the store needs to have a "tooltip" attribute for each value - dojo will use that to populate the tooltip